# Can osquery generate apt package information like it does rpm?

Tags: apt, osquery

I'm looking to generate lists of apt package versions for specific packages, like sudo,ssh, etc. OSQuery seems to have an option to generate this with rpm_packages however I can find no mention of apt_packages.

I don't mean apt_sources, and the apps table appears to be a MacOS only thing.

I might be just missing a table listing versions of binaries.

Comment: Oh. the .file table has this information; kinda. Just has to be enabled.

Comment: The .file table only has file information, not binary version information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the [`deb_packages`](https://osquery.io/schema/4.6.0/#deb_packages) table?

`apps` is macOS specific, as it enumerates the macOS Applications.

Comment: This was it exactly. I cannot believe I missed this. Thank you.